# How to get number of files in a 7z

Tags: shell-script, 7z, sparse-files

I want to get the number of files (included directories) contained in the root of a 7z archive, but the `7z` command on Linux don’t bring a simple way to only get the number and noting else.

For example I have the `7zarchive.7z` file witch contain `archive.tar` and `archive.gzip`. Then, `7z l 7zarchive.7z` print me the following verbose lines:

```
7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=fr_FR.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Listing archive: 7zarchive.7z

--
Path = 7zarchive.7z
Type = 7z
Method = LZMA
Solid = +
Blocks = 1
Physical Size = 495
Headers Size = 184

    Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2016-03-14 22:43:10 ....A        20480          311  archive.tar
2016-03-14 23:04:01 ....A          163               archive.gzip
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                             20643          311  2 files, 0 folders
```

In the right bottom, you can see “2 files, 0 folders”, so I want to get the sum of number of folders and number of files.

For this, I try the flowing hideous command :
`bash
7z l 7z l *.7z  | tail -1 | sed -e 's/.* \([0-9]*\) files\, \([0-9]*\) folders/\1 \2/' -e 's/\([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\$(( \1 + \2))/'  | tail -1 | sed -e 's/.* \([0-9]*\) files\, \([0-9]*\) folders/\1 \2/' -e 's/\([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\$(( \1 + \2))/'`

1. `tail` extract the last line;
2. The first `sed` expression extract the numbers before the words “files” and “folders”.
3. The second `sed` expression formate it to be printed like this `$(( <first number> + <second number>))`.

So, I really obtain the output `$(( 2 + 0))`, but I want it to be executed to get only the result (2) and not the command to calculate the result.

So, there is a way to do this, or, at list, a more simple way to get the number of files contained by a 7z archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find it, it was more simple that I imagine: `7z l -slt <nameof archive> | grep -c 'Path = [^/]*$'`.

Comment: This code counts the archive itself because the output of `7z l -slt` includes a section for it. For example, for an archive containing two files, this code will output `3`.

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler if you use positional values, e.g.,

```
7z l 7zarchive.7z | tail -n 1 |awk '{ print $3 + $5; }'
```

giving the total of files + folders.

In the last line

```
20643          311  2 files, 0 folders
```

`$1` is *"20643*", `$2` is *"311"*, `$3` is *"2"*, `$4` is *"files,*", `$5` is *"0"* and `$6` is *"folders"*.  You could make it more definite using a regular expression to match the line.

Comment: I qualified the comment with a note about a regular expression before you made a comment about it.

Comment: It’s also a good solution but this also count subfiles and subdirectories.